# "Invalid literal value for picklist:" Error when deploying WorkflowFieldUpdate via ANT

Tags: deployment, metadata, ant

Workflow Field Update is failing to deploy/validate due to the following error:

`Invalid literal value for picklist:<yourPicklistValue>`

What causes this?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the picklist value that is being used in this WorkflowFieldUpdate is not present in the Target org. Make sure to include the Field being updated in the package OR make sure that the picklist value exists in the Target org.

Comment: This file I've pulled from production, is found in Setup > User Interface > Global Actions (shows up in the metadata under quickActions) is throwing ye olde  `Invalid literal value for picklist:Open` when I try to deploy source to a scratch org..  but I can't for the life of me figure out what picklist allows this to work in production

Comment: Ok.. I had to do some voo-doo with the manifest/package.xml to pull down my picklist file for `TaskStatus` and once that became part of my project (TaskStatus.standardValueSet-meta-xml) I was good to go